Unexpected behavior in Javascript
Using the below code, I see unexpected behavior in Javascript: When clicking on any items, the website navigates to lifestyle/[id], but it does not render correct content or it raises 404 error. Why is this happening?
Below is the content of components/lifestyle.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import _ from 'lodash';

const Lifestyle = ({ news }) => {
 const sortedNews = _.sortBy(news, 'published_date').reverse();
  
 return (
  <div>
   <h1 className="text-2xl sm:text-3xl text-center text-black font-bold p-1 rounded-xl">LifeStyle</h1>
   {sortedNews.length > 0 && (
    <div className='flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center p-2 lg:pr-3 gap-2 lg:border-r-2 border-gray-400'>
     {sortedNews.slice(0,3).map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index} className='flex flex-row lg:flex-col w-full lg:w-1/3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 '>
       <Link href={`/${item.category}/${item.id}` } legacyBehavior>
        <a>
         <img src={item.image_url} alt={item.title} className='object-cover h-auto lg:h-36 w-4/6 lg:w-full p-1 rounded-lg' />
         <h1 className='text-black w-2/6 lg:w-full p-2 font-bold text-2xl md:text-lg'>{item.title}</h1>
        </a>
       </Link>
      </div>
     ))}
    </div>
   )}
  </div>
 );
};

export default Lifestyle;


// pages/[category]/[id].js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NewsItemPage = () => {
 const router = useRouter();
 const { id, category } = router.query;

 return (
  <div>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   <p>Category: {category}</p>
   <p>News ID: {id}</p>
  </div>
 );
};

export default NewsItemPage;


Below is the local directories tree:

app
├── pages
│  ├── [category]
│  │  └── [id].js
├── components
│  ├── Lifestyle.jsx
│  └── // other components
├── api
│  └── news
│    └── route.js
└── // other files



I am trying to get the ID and category from the URL: http://localhost:3000/lifestyle/41

use the link component without legacyBehavior prop.
